# Airflow LDAP superuser authentication

Tags: ldap, airflow

I am using Airflow v1.9.0 and am trying to setup groups using LDAP authentication.
I can get the basic LDAP authentication working that defaults all users to be superusers. However, I cannot get the AD to match against a specific group. For instance, I have user TommyLeeJones who I know is part of the user group MIB, but I can't get airflow to match this user against this group.

In my airflow.cfg file, I have set:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth

[ldap]
user_filter = objectClass=*
user_name_attr=sAMAccountName
```

In my webserver.env file, I have:

`AIRFLOW__LDAP__URI=zartha.men.in.black:389
AIRFLOW__LDAP__BIND_USER=men\TommyLeeJones
AIRFLOW__LDAP__BIND_PASSWORD=APersonIsSmartPeopleAreDumb      AIRFLOW__LDAP__SUPERUSER_FILTER=memberOf=CN=MIB,OU=UK,OU=Groups,DC=men,DC=in,DC=black
AIRFLOW__LDAP__DATA_PROFILER_FILTER=memberOf=CN=MIB,OU=UK,OU=Groups,DC=men,DC=in,DC=black
AIRFLOW__LDAP__BASEDN=DC=men,DC=in,DC=black
AIRFLOW__LDAP__SEARCH_SCOPE=SUBTREE`

I can login, but not as a superuser which I should be able to.

Comment: Confirm your `AIRFLOW__LDAP__SUPERUSER_FILTER` is correct and that you have that role for your account. 99% sure that's your issue, always seems to be my LDAP issue

Comment: I found the issue, the webserver.env file complains when there are spaces in the CN or OU values and wrapping it in quotes ends in an error. Just found another group that doesn't have spaces in the CN or OU values.

Comment: Great @cal, I put this as _the_ answer

Comment: I confirm the problem with spaces inside CN and OU.

Answer (score 0):

When working with LDAP, I find that I'm usually misspelling my LDAP query.

Confirm that `AIRFLOW__LDAP__SUPERUSER_FILTER` is correct.

You can use [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/) Python package and confirm from the command line this works.