# How can I setup the Airflow AD/LDAP superuser_filter and data_profiler_filter with RBAC turned on?

Tags: ldap, airflow, pyldap

I am using Airflow 1.10.10, and I have successfully set up AD/LDAP integration internally while also having `rbac = True` in the airflow configuration file. I set this up by following this resource https://guptakumartanuj.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/airflow-ui-authentication-through-ldap-server/ and a few others with similar setups. However now that I have this set up, I don't want to force every new user to either be an `Admin` or a `Viewer` and would rather have that be dictated by their corresponding AD groups. With this current setup, the variables below either allow you to make a new user an Admin or a Viewer:

`AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True`

`AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"`

I tried adding the `AIRFLOW__LDAP__SUPERUSER_FILTER` and data_profiler arguments to my `webserver_config.py` file but I am still unable to allow the user to inherit permissions from the AD groups.

For reference, my filters are setup with the following syntax:
`memberOf=CN=ADMINTEAM,OU=SvcAccts,DC=us,DC=ae`

Can anyone help? I also tried disabling `AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION` but this just takes away the AD functionality ..

Comment: Check if this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931466/airflow-ldap-superuser-authentication

Comment: Where you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi @BrainMonkey, not for permission inheritance. But I figured out how to filter airflow logins to a specific LDAP group.